# view pager set current item does not work properly

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I use AHBottomNavigationViewPager.

When i set AHBottomNavigationViewPager current item, two fragments open.

For example: when i set 0 for current item, fagments with position 0 and 1 open and their codes will run.

What is problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

View pager load side by side fragment.
If you set 0 position then fragment 0 and 1 will load,
If you set 1 then load 0 ,1 and 2 position fragment.
If you set 2 set load 1,2 and 3 position fragment.

More details
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: can i disable it? I want only one fragment with selected position loaded.

Comment: No,you can not disable. If you want selected position then you tabhost or tablayout.

Comment: Or you have other hack way option load empty fragment at position 1. Use 0 then load your fragment and load empty fragment and use 2 then load another one. But recommend do not use this bad way

Comment: It is sad :) So i get current fragment and if it is for selected item, run fragment methods. You have a better solution?

Comment: Sorry bro there is no solution, if you use view pager then you can not do

Comment: I think i can do it, in fragment i call one method of  the activity which view pager is in and method return current view pager item. if my fragment was equal returned item, run fragment methods. Are you sure that's not possible?

Comment: Yes, u need to load fragment dynamically

Comment: Thanks, will my problem resolved by this: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/dynamically-add-fragments-to-an-activity-in-android/